# Update an existing data in elastic search via logstash for mongoDb?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, logstash

I am not able to update the existing data in ES via logstash for mongoDb.
When i insert any data it gets indexed into elastic but when I Update it doesn't get updated.

```
  output {
    stdout {}
 elasticsearch {
                action => "index"
                index => "mongo_log_data"
                hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        }
```

If I use action as update the logstash is throwing exception.

Comment: It might help to see what exception you're getting

Comment: logstash is here to parse a incoming log, and index it into ES.
Update your data using ES api

Comment: But in logstash we also have action => "update". Shouldn't that action update the changes.

Comment: Hi @Val that exception got resolved.Thanks

Comment: elasticsearch {
                document_id => "%{username}"
                action => "update"
                doc_as_upsert => true
                index => "mongo_log_data"
                hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        }

Comment: @Jean-JacquesMOIROUX Logstash can do updates too ;-)

Comment: @Val elasticsearch { document_id => "%{username}" action => "update" doc_as_upsert => true index => "mongo_log_data" hosts => ["localhost:9200"] } . This statement is inserting but not updating the existing data.